# Adjust background image to div size using File API

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filereader

I have an issue at the moment,

I'm using a set of image blocks for an upload system, as shown below.

[image]

When i click on each of the squares who are `input type="file"` i get the image preview with the [File reader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), all of that is working fine, what i do is replace the background image of the div (whose dimensions are 100px X 100px) for the preview, using

```
.css( "background", 'url(' + e.target.result + ')' )
```

But the image doesn't adjust to the div width and height, and it shows only one portion.

I tried with css map setting `"background-size": "100%"` or even `"background-size": "100px 100px"`, but the results remain the same.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about `background-size:contain;`?

Comment: @APAD1 I'll give it a try and answer back.

Comment: @APAD1 add it as an answer. but cover did the trick thanks for the guidance.

Comment: You can go ahead and accept @JacquesMarais answer, they need the points more than I do ;) Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `background-size` css property to `contain`, just like this:

```
.css( "background-size", 'contain' )
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Values) for more information.

Note: As commented by Rory McCrossan setting the `background-size` to `cover` will also work, that's when you don't mind cropping the image.

Comment: `cover` would also work, if you want to maintain the size of the thumbnail, and don't mind cropping.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually cover did the trick for my particular situation :)